# How to update quantity if same item chosen?

Tags: php, session

I'm going to use the `session['cart']` elsewehere on the site to show the items chosen by user..(e-commerce). So I wish to perform 'addition' on quantity data if item chosen is same.

```
<?php
session_start();

$return = $_POST;
//$return ='{"qty":"54","id":"8375","action":"test"}';

$return['json']= json_encode($return);

$data = json_decode($return['json'], true);

if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
 $_SESSION['cart']=array();
}
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], array("quantity"=>$data['qty'],"id"=>$data['id']));

echo json_encode($_SESSION['cart']);
  ?>
```

DO I add 'quantity' here or in the place where  display the session data like below?

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k=>$v)
{

    ?>
 <tr><th><?php echo $v['id'];?></th><th><?php echo $v['quantity'];?></th></tr>

    <?php

}
?>
```

Comment: How about `$_SESSION['cart']['quantity'] += 1;` as the quickest (and of course not cleanest) way

Answer (score 0):

This is my a little cleaner implementation:

```
// create new cart if needed
if (empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

// check if item with id exists in cart
if (array_key_exists($data['id'], $_SESSION['cart']) {
    // update quantity only
    $_SESSION['cart'][$data['id']] = $data['qty']; // or you can increment it 
} else {
    // add item to cart with defined quantity
    $_SESSION['cart'][$data['id']] = array(
        'id' => $data['id'],
        'quantity' => $data['qty'],
    );
}

echo json_encode($_SESSION['cart']);
```